# Random repeats similar strings, even after changing seed

Tags: php, random

How can I get this random string generator to create random strings. I keep getting repeats. The arrays generally consist of between 0 - 10 things, but still it is getting the same number of beds and baths on the repeats, I know that statistically it is messed up.

How can I elminate repeats?

```
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 1000000; $i++) {

      srand($i);
      $price = rand(20000, 1000000);
      $bed = rand(0, 20);
      $bath = rand(0, 7);
      $addressnum = rand(100, 10000);
      $address = (int) preg_replace('/\D/', '', $addressnum) . " lol st";
      $province = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
      $postedby = 3;
      $description = $de_contents[rand(0,count($de_contents) - 1)];
      $status = "Unsold";
      $type = $status_a[array_rand($status_a)];
      $category = $category_type[array_rand($category_type)];
      $size = rand(100,100000);
      $builtin = rand(1850, 2013);

      $queryString = "INSERT INTO listings 
      (PRICE, ADDRESS, PROVINCE, DESCRIPTION, STATUS, TYPE, CATEGORY, SIZE, BUILTIN, BED, BATH, POSTED_BY) VALUES 
      ($price, '$address', '$province', '$description', '$status', '$type', '$category', $size, $builtin, $bed, $bath, $postedby)";
      echo $queryString . "<br>"; 
      $query = $db -> query($queryString);
    }
```

Comment: You get identical values for `$queryString`? Why are you using `srand($i)`? Have you tried replacing `rand()` with `mt_rand()`?

Comment: what can I replace array_rand with?

Comment: Try replacing `$status_a[array_rand($status_a)]` with `$status_a[mt_rand(count($status_a))]` and all calls to `rand()` with calls to `mt_rand()`

Comment: @offtopic, so your generating fake listings?

Comment: yeah, for testing purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using rand().  Using mt_rand() instead should solve this problem.

I've come across problems several times with rand() and repeated values. I have to admit that in those cases I never really took the time to check why rand() seems so wonky.

Answer (score 0):

Take `srand()` outside the loop. `srand()` should be called ONCE, and only once, in your program. Thereafter, `rand()` will produce random results. If you call `srand()` repeatedly, you're not getting random numbers at all, you're getting a hash value of the seeds you call it with.

Sure, switching to `mt_rand()` will give you even higher-quality random numbers, but that wasn't the problem with your code.